# Node wont make connection to server with self signed certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl, dns, portforwarding

A little background:
I have a Tesla Powerwall which has it's own built in web server that can be accessed on the local network. It only allows SSL connections and uses a self signed certificate. I have setup port forwarding that allows me to connect to the web server remotely. For a while, i've had working `node.js` apps both on a local `Pi` and also a remote `AWS` instance that made requests to the Powerwall web server to retrieve bits of information.

Since yesterday, Tesla updated my Powerwall and now everything has stopped working. I can only assume they have changed something regarding how the web server handles it's self signed SSL certificate.

Firstly, my `Pi` running on the local network would not make successful `node.js` requests to the local server. I managed to get this working by adding an entry to my `/etc/hosts` file like this:

> 192.168.1.42    powerwall

and now my `node.js` app can successfully connect again using `https://powerwall`

When using `Safari` or `Chrome` to connect remotely, I can connect if I use my IP address (After trusting the self signed cert) but cannot connect when using my `DDNS` address that points to home. (I have confirmed the DDNS is working). It gives me the error:

> Safari can’t open the page “https://home.xxxxxx.com:4444” because Safari can’t establish a secure connection to the server “ home.xxxxxx.com”.

My `AWS` `node.js` app will not connect regardless of me using the IP address or DDNS address giving me the error:

> Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

This is how I am trying to connect:

```
request({
    url: 'https://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/api/system_status/soe',
    method: 'GET',
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    requestCert: true,
    agent: false,
    headers: headers
}
```

I have tried adding:

```
secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_method'
```

and attempted with the methods `TLSv1_method` `TLSv1_1_method` `TLSv1_2_method` in case it needed a specific method, with no luck.

Does the above sound like the SSL settings on the server have been screwed down?
What can I do to:

a) access the site remotely through a browser using the `DDNS` address

b) force `node.js` to not be interested in the SSL certificate at all and just connect

----- EDIT

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            46:.....
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
        Issuer: C=US, ST=California, L=Palo Alto, O=Tesla, OU=Tesla Energy Products, CN=335cbec3e3d8baee7742f095bd4f8f17
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar 29 22:17:28 2019 GMT
            Not After : Mar 22 22:17:28 2044 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=California, L=Palo Alto, O=Tesla, OU=Tesla Energy Products, CN=335cbec3e3d8baee7742f095bd4f8f17
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (256 bit)
                pub: 
                    04:ca...
                ASN1 OID: prime256v1
                NIST CURVE: P-256
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:teg, DNS:powerwall, DNS:powerpack, IP Address:192.168.90.1, IP Address:192.168.90.2, IP Address:192.168.91.1
```

Comment: You say `I have confirmed the DDNS is working`. How?

Comment: If I ping the DDNS it returns my home IP. Also I have other stuff running off the DDNS that works. And finally, it was working perfectly until Tesla updated the software on the Powerwall.

Comment: I suspect they changed the hostname provided in the self-signed cert. Download the certificate you get in Safari and then run command: `openssl x509 -in /path/to/cert -noout -text` and add the output to your question. You can leave out the hex blocks in `Modulus` and `Signature Algorithm` sections

Comment: Check my addition to the answer below

Comment: Certificate added above. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With HTTPS, the domain needs to match what’s signed in the cert; it’s usually the public domain.
It’s not supposed to be the IP, and it certainly won't be the DDNS hostname (if I understood correctly) you’re pointing at it.

There are 3 possible approaches;

1. Add the certificate from the powerwall as a ‘known’ rootCA (as already suggested),
2. Tell node.js to skip checking the validity of the certificate, or
3. Try with HTTP

Proper operation of the HTTPS connection process will also depend on you accessing the powerwall using the *domain name registered in the certificate* (which may require your DNS server to respond with the appropriate IP when the lookup is made ~> like DNS spoofing proof-of-concept for a CTF).

Also, to your musings in comments, while some browsers may allow you to override an expired or self-signed cert (or when connecting via IP), but it’s *very* sketchy to connect with a domain and get a cert that specifies and entirely different domain (which is why the browser might not even present you the option).

HTH

**Post-resolution update:**

- How to get the DNS name to match what's on the certificate:

  - add an entry in the client system's `/etc/hosts` or equivalent
  - connect using the hostname (not the IP)

When connecting over public Internet:

- How to get public-internet connections through to the local host:

  - get a [public-facing HTTPS cert (e.g.)](https://letsencrypt.org)  that matches your DDNS domain or `/etc/hosts` entry
  - Host a HTTP-proxy

    - relay requests from Internet (hopefully with filtering/validation) to the `powerwall`
    - (you will have 2 HTTPS connections: one from AWS -> proxy, one from proxy->powerwall)
  - Host a custom API that will return exactly the [minimum] info needed by the AWS service
- How to trust a self-signed certificate? (this wasn't the blocking factor)

Comment: Unfortunately none of the above 3 suggestions worked. I think the web server in the Powerwall is rejecting any connections from anything that looks like a DNS address. IP's work and https://powerwall/ works. 2, this is what I was initially trying to do, but thought I was struggling to make it work, and now I know it's down to the web server and not the node code. 3, It automatically redirects http to https, so it has nothing served over http.

Comment: DNS names only apply to the server in a connection, not the client. So when connecting using the powerwall dns name, the issue is the self-signed certificate? If the hostname lookup is failing, you can use an entry in your hosts file to point ‘powerwall’ at the [hopefully static] IP.

Comment: To the end of getting your system (which CA is trusted happens above the nodeJs level), try this: https://superuser.com/questions/1359755/trust-self-signed-cert-in-chrome-macos-10-13. For more on the ‘why’ you can look into Certificates’ ‘chain of trust’

Comment: Re-reading, once local access from the Pi works, the solution will need to be ported to AWS. The key will be to either: configure the AWS instance’s hosts (or equivalent) to point at your home IP, or have 2 HTTPS segments: one from AWS to (e.g.) your Pi, then from the Pi to the powerwall. (You can use LetsEncrypt) to get a recognized cert for your DDNS domain)

Comment: Your last comment seems obvious now. Port what I did on the Pi to AWS. I have added `powerwall` to the hosts file and it does now work :) The only problem, is it needs me to enter my IP address which is dynamic and why I use a DDNS instead. Is there a way to use a DNS address in the hosts file? I'm assuming not. I tried to get the AWS->Pi->PW working, but I couldn't figure out how to correctly setup apache to simply be the middleman between the https requests.

Comment: Glad you found the hosts file for AWS! Sounds like that won’t be the long-term fix due to dynamic IP. If HTTPS relay using apache (?) doesn’t work, there’s always the option of just mirroring the powerwall endpoints on your Pi (in nodeJs code); keep in mind you may need to add 1-2 more to get a HTTPS cert valid for your DDNS domain. TBH the simplest route to HTTPS in to the Pi may be to just use something like ngrok (the free version gives a new subdomain each time, but handles the HTTPS for you).

Comment: This may be a [security] footgun, but you may want to try nginx over apache: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy. You’ll need 1) a HTTPS cert for your DDNS, 2) nginx to forward _specific_ (the narrower, the more secure) endpoints to https://powerwall , and 3) some way of validating that the inbound request is actually authorized by you  (secret key or signed JWT, preferably in AWS env vars; maybe check the origin IP against AWS’s IPs for the expected region; etc.) Remeber: the LinkedIn breach was caused by an employee’s insecure home webserver

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have it working with node endpoints on my Pi :) Your last statement about the LinkedIn breach suggests I should forget about trying to access the power wall directly, so I'm happy with how it's working now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for debugging:

```
openssl s_client \
-connect 192.168.1.42:4444 \
-CAfile /path/to/self-signed-cert \
-verify_hostname powerwall \
-debug
```

Can find more options in `openssl s_client -help`

Do you have any servers running on your home network (apache, nginx, etc)? You're probably trying to connect to `https://my.ddns.com` and you're passing it directly to powerwall, which has a certificate for `powerwall`.

Connecting to a host that returns a certificate which does not contain that hostname will cause a TLS error. You probably want to run a forward proxy, where your server hosts `my.ddns.com`, sets up the TLS connection and then forwards the traffic (without TLS) to `192.168.1.44`.

Comment: Which cert would I use for the `self-signed-cert` file? I don't have access to the private cert, only the public one I can obtain from Safari.

Comment: Use the one you can get from safari, there's no private cert just a private key.

Comment: `unknown option -verify_hostname` when running the above command

Comment: I can see where this is going though. The certificate is only valid for the hostname `powerwall` so I need to be using that when accessing it? I do in fact have an apache server running on a Pi, so I will try and setup a forward proxy. I think a problem might be that the powerwall web server only seems to accept a TLS connection (It forwards http to https).

Comment: I'm still a little puzzled as to why I can use the IP address and tell Safari to accept the cert, but using the DDNS address I don't get the option to accept the cert, it just fails. Do you think this could be down to how Tesla have configured the web server on the Powerwall to maybe reject any DNS type addresses, but accept IP addresses?

Comment: I'm not sure, I"m not a mac guy, but it's something to do with the internal mechanics of Safari. Perhaps if you go right to an IP the browser will give you an option to examine and accept the cert, but if you do a hostname and the cert doesn't match it just kills the connection. Making unilateral decisions "in your best interest" is the apple programmer's guiding philosophy.